# How to have more than one person edit google sheet without seeing each others changes?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have created a timesheet for employees to fill out in google sheets with a button that then sends me that filled out timesheet in PDF form to my email. I am trying to figure out how to handle multiple people filling out the form at the same time since I can't have two people filling out the same timesheet.

Is there a way to create an 'instance' of sorts for sheets? Thanks!

Comment: Make it a [webapp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) so that every only sees their stuff.  All you need is a couple of textboxes and a button.

Comment: Can you require that they have Gmail Accounts? This is also in regards to your new question.

Comment: Assuming that you can require your users to have Gmail Accounts and if your willing to get a business account then you could let them become a part of a team drive and you could use a StandAlone WebApp to access files in the team drive which means that while anyone could find the script and run it.  It would only respond to people that have access to the team drive.  Which gives you a little extra security.  It would perfect to give your users gmail accounts that are inside your own domain.  It comes with a monthly charge but it adds a lot of extra security. It is a way to deploy a webapp.

Comment: Since you code is pretty simple it should be relatively easy to use Lock Service.  How many users do you have?